# How to find paths to GC roots

Tags: java, memory-management

Is there a pure-java way to find which references are keeping an instance from being GCd (specifically, a class loader instance)? Is there a way to at least count number of references to an existing class loader instance?

A possible solution would be to use ref-counter, but I cannot control all the code that references these class loader instances and I believe JVM must already have counters. Can I access them?

Comment: Is it that you just want to know how `GC` actually works or there is some specific reason for doing this?

Comment: A reference counter. Or use static variables.

Comment: I'm building a package that sits in a user's application server and holds references to objects of classes I define and load on the fly from user's class-loaders.
If I use weak-ref to point to my objects, my objects die pretty quickly cause nothing else holds them. If I use a strong reference, my objects prevent user's class-loaders from being GCd.
I'm looking for a way to know that I'm the only one left holding them alive, but without actually holding them (like a self-cleaning auto-pointer).